# Difference between Mortality Rate, Crude Death Rate and Cause-Specific Death Rate

Tags: epidemiology, mortality

Like the title explains, I'm having a difficulty understanding the differences between:

1. Mortality Rate
2. Crude Death Rate
3. Cause-Specific Death Rate.

Somebody please explain the differences.

Comment: What have you already learned about the subject? Where are you stuck on the definitions?